# How to verify regedit result?

Tags: batch-file, regedit

How do I verify the value of a regedit query request?

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /V "HiberbootEnabled" 
IF result == 1 goto turoff
IF result == 0 goto turnon
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just wanting to toggle the value betwen `1` and `0`, something along these lines may work for you, *(as long as you have the appropriate permissions to access/modify the value data)*.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "DWord="
For /F "Tokens=3" %%A In ('
    Reg Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /V "HiberbootEnabled" 2^>Nul
') Do 2>Nul Set /A DWord=1-%%A
If Defined DWord Reg Add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /V "HiberbootEnabled" /T REG_DWORD /D %DWord% /F>Nul
```

Comment: To toggle between 0 and 1 you could also use `Set /A "DWord=!%%A"` both are less obvious than an if but IMO more elegant. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`find`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) or [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to filter the line needed, and then use `for /f` to read the output

```bat
for /f "tokens=3" %%v in ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /V "HiberbootEnabled" ^| find "HiberbootEnabled"') do set result=%%v
if "%result%" == "0x1" (
    turnoff
) else (
    turnon
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be found lots of articles in world wide web on how to change the fast startup setting of Windows 8 and later Windows versions.

Here is one more commented batch file solution which must be **run as administrator**:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for /F "skip=2 tokens=1-3" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /v "HiberBootEnabled" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%A" == "HiberBootEnabled" set /A "HiberBootEnabled=%%C" & goto EvaluateValue
)

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('ver') do set "WindowsVersion=%%I"
echo Fast startup (hibernate boot) setting not found in Windows registry.
echo/
echo %WindowsVersion% does not support fast startup.
goto EndBatch

:EvaluateValue
rem Toggle the hibernate boot setting.
if %HiberBootEnabled% == 0 (set "HiberBootEnabled=1") else set "HiberBootEnabled=0"

rem Change the hibernate boot setting in registry if batch file
rem is executed with elevated permissions of a local administrator.
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /f /v "HiberBootEnabled" /t REG_DWORD /d %HiberBootEnabled% >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto ErrorAddValue

if %HiberBootEnabled% == 0 (set "HiberBootEnabled=OFF") else set "HiberBootEnabled=ON"
echo Fast startup (hibernate boot) setting toggled %HiberBootEnabled%.
goto EndBatch

:ErrorAddValue
echo/
echo %~nx0 must be run as administrator to toggle the
echo fast startup (hibernate boot) setting in Windows registry.

:EndBatch
echo/
pause
endlocal
```

This batch file is designed for being executed on Windows XP / Windows Server 2003 and all newer Windows versions. There is nothing done if Windows does not already have the double word registry value `HiberBootEnabled` because of not supporting fast startup. It also does nothing if the batch file is executed without elevated privileges of a local administrator required for write access to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` registry hive.

Here is also an optimized version using the simple and great method to subtract from `1` the current value of the double word to toggle it as posted by [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) in his answer.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for /F "skip=2 tokens=1-3" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /v "HiberBootEnabled" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%A" == "HiberBootEnabled" set /A "HiberBootEnabled=1-%%C" & goto ToggleValue
)

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('ver') do set "WindowsVersion=%%I"
echo Fast startup (hibernate boot) setting not found in Windows registry.
echo/
echo %WindowsVersion% does not support fast startup.
goto EndBatch

:ToggleValue
rem Change the hibernate boot setting in registry if batch file
rem is executed with elevated permissions of a local administrator.
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /f /v "HiberBootEnabled" /t REG_DWORD /d %HiberBootEnabled% >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto ErrorAddValue

if %HiberBootEnabled% == 0 (set "HiberBootEnabled=OFF") else set "HiberBootEnabled=ON"
echo Fast startup (hibernate boot) setting toggled %HiberBootEnabled%.
goto EndBatch

:ErrorAddValue
echo/
echo %~nx0 must be run as administrator to toggle
echo the hibernate boot setting in Windows registry.

:EndBatch
echo/
pause
endlocal
```

And even better would be as fifth line according to suggestion by [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings):

```
    if /I "%%A" == "HiberBootEnabled" set /A "HiberBootEnabled=!%%C" & goto ToggleValue
```

This line sets `HiberBootEnabled` to `0` even if the current value is greater `1`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` .. explains `%~nx0` (name of batch file with extension)
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg add /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`